# Django urls accepting an object or Dictionary

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, href, django-urls

As i am new to django i am not aware of the advanced django url concept.
So i would like to know whether the following are possible or not in django urls.

My first Question is,

In my django template i am calling this url,

```
<a href="/product/mycart/{{val.price}}">
```

I used the below url for the above href

```
url(r'^mycart/(?P<val.price>\d+)/$', 'cartList')
```

But it shows the below error,

```
error at /product/list/

bad character in group name
```

My second question is in my django template i have the following

```
val.price=some value

val.id=some value

val.hieght=some value
```

now iam calling this below url

```
<a class="add_to_cart" href="/product/mycart/{{val}}" title="Product Cart">Add To Cart</a>
```

i used the below url for the above href

```
url(r'^mycart/(?P<val>\d+)/$', 'cartList')
```

but it shows the below error

```
Page not found (404)
```

please help me out these problems.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**for your first question**

You better name your url:

```
url(r'^mycart/(?P<val.price>\d+)/$', 'cartList', name="cart_list)
```

Then in your template you could use

```
<a href="{% url cart_list val.price %}">
```

**For your second question**

both of the urls look the same to me and my guess is that django can't see the difference between the to. Try using different urls

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do by putting `val.price` into the URL pattern itself? That makes no sense. What's inside the named group is the parameter that gets passed into the view. You need to use a valid Python variable identifier: you can't define a function in Python as `def cart_list(request, val.price)`, so you can't use that in the URL conf. Why can't you just use `price`?

Your second question makes no sense either. What, exactly, would be the URL that you put into the browser to send that `val` object? A urlpattern has to resolve to an actual URL.

It's impossible to know what you are actually trying to do, but perhaps you want to pass the object's database ID? Then your receiving view can look up the object in the db by its ID, extract the price, and add it to the cart.

Comment: hi daniel .please note that i am calling my url from the django template. So the variable that i used to pass the parameter from the template  only be accepted in the url . So i have to use the same variable in both url and django template. Its not been a problem to me whats happening in the function definition. Please go through my question once again......

Comment: No, you need to think logically about this. You do *not* need to use "the same variable in both URL and Django template". Of course you don't. You need to use the same name in the URL and the view that it calls. But in the template you would just do `<a href="/product/mycart/{{val.price}}">` as you have, and your URLconf is `r'^mycart/(?P<price>\d+)/$'`.